# STM32F4 USB VCP, PC receive all 0x00

Tags: microcontroller, usb, stm32, usb-device, stm32f4

I'm a beginner in STM32F4 and I'm learning how to use the USB Virtual COM Port ("VCP") to transmit data from the microcontroller to a PC.

The virtual port is detected as "STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port", and I use serial monitoring software to see the data received by the PC.

The PC is receiving all 0x00 no matter what I send in my code.

I called VCP_DataTx() function to send data.

Any ideas about what's wrong?

p.s. in my main() function, I only called USBD_Init() to initialize USB Device, is that enough? Did I miss anything that should be configured? I see someone say USART when talk about VCP, is there any relationship between them?

Thanks.

This is my main.cpp. I did nothing more but initialize USB device and send data.

```
#include "usbd_cdc_core.h"
#include "usbd_usr.h"
#include "usb_conf.h"
#include "usbd_desc.h"

#include "usbd_cdc_vcp.h"

USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE    USB_OTG_dev;
uint8_t Buf[6] = "A";

int main(void)
{
  __IO uint32_t i = 0;  

  USBD_Init(&USB_OTG_dev,         
            USB_OTG_FS_CORE_ID,
            &USR_desc, 
            &USBD_CDC_cb, 
            &USR_cb);

    VCP_DataTx(Buf, 6);

  /* Main loop */
  while (1)
  {
      VCP_DataTx(Buf, 6);
      while (i < 0x77ffff)
      {
          i++;
      }
  }
}
```

In order to call VCP_DataTx() in main, I deleted *static* keyword in usbd_cdc_vcp.h and usbd_cdc.vcp.c

p.p.s. I didn't realize usbd_cdc_vcp.c is not in STM USB library. It comes from the VCP example in STM32_USB-Host-Device_Lib_V2.1.0, and the function VCP_DataTx() looks like:

```
uint16_t VCP_DataTx (uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t Len)
{
  if (linecoding.datatype == 7)
  {
    APP_Rx_Buffer[APP_Rx_ptr_in] = USART_ReceiveData(EVAL_COM1) & 0x7F;
  }
  else if (linecoding.datatype == 8)
  {
    APP_Rx_Buffer[APP_Rx_ptr_in] = USART_ReceiveData(EVAL_COM1);
  }

  APP_Rx_ptr_in++;

  /* To avoid buffer overflow */
  if(APP_Rx_ptr_in == APP_RX_DATA_SIZE)
  {
    APP_Rx_ptr_in = 0;
  }  

  return USBD_OK;
}
```

Comment: Do you receive the "correct" number of 0x00's?  That is, if you attempt to send 5 bytes do you receive 5 zero-bytes?

Comment: Show your part of the code where  you call VCP_DataTX()

Comment: @bitsmack: yes, the number is correct. But it's only correct with the times I call VCP_DataTx(). If I call that function for 10 times, and transmit 6 bytes every time I call it, I get 10 0x00's rather than 60.

Comment: Your function "uint16_t VCP_DataTx (uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t Len)" uses neither Buf nor Len.

Comment: @Tut: Yes, I did't notice that this function doesn't use Buf nor Len. I thought it is an official example, but ignored the data comes from USART, not Buf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using the ST USB Library for a different ST ARM microcontroller (STM32F105), but the structure looks the same. I, too, have based my code off of the VCP example.

First, there is some additional initialization required for the USB to work. Following is a list of things to verify. You may new to adjust some of these examples to work with your microcontroller:

1. You need to have enabled the `OTG_FS_IRQHandler` interrupt:

   ```
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = OTG_FS_IRQn;
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 7;
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
   NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
   ```

   The following is in my interrupt vector file:

   ```
   #include "usb_core.h"
   #include "usbd_core.h"
   #include "usbd_cdc_core.h"

   extern USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE USB_OTG_dev;
   extern uint32_t USBD_OTG_ISR_Handler (USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev);

   void OTG_FS_IRQHandler(void)
   {
       USBD_OTG_ISR_Handler (&USB_OTG_dev);
   } // end OTG_FS_IRQHandler()
   ```
2. You must select and enable a 48 MHz clock source for the OTG/USB model before calling `USBD_Init`. In my case, this was derived by dividing the 144 MHz PLLVCO by 3. The clock tree can be tricky; make sure you understand that section of the Reference Manual.

   ```
   // Configure USB Clock Source
   RCC_OTGFSCLKConfig(RCC_OTGFSCLKSource_PLLVCO_Div3);

   // Enable USB Clock
   RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_OTG_FS, ENABLE);
   ```
3. In the USB Library is the `usb_conf.h` file. This is a tangle of conditional defines. Make sure that these are actually getting defined (if they are appropriate to your application):

   ```
   #define USE_USB_OTG_FS
   #define USB_OTG_FS_CORE
   #define USE_EMBEDDED_PHY
   #define VBUS_SENSING_ENABLED
   #define USE_DEVICE_MODE
   ```

---

Next, as @Tut pointed out in the comments, your `VCP_DataTX` function needs modification. It is currently using the USART peripheral as the source of the USB data.  You want to change it so that it uses `Buf` and `Len`. Even though the function call includes the `Buf` and `Len` arguments, these aren't actually used in the function.

The `VCP_DataTx` stuffs data, one byte at a time, into the `APP_Rx_Buffer` array. Every time it writes a byte to the array it also increments the `APP_Rx_ptr_in` value. This buffer is regularly checked and processed by the OTG/USB library code.

My function looks like this:

```
uint16_t VCP_DataTx(uint8_t *Buf, uint32_t Len)
{
    uint32_t i;

    // Put the data into the buffer. It will be processed by the USB stack.
    for (i=0; i<Len; i++)
    {
        // Add a byte to the buffer
        APP_Rx_Buffer[APP_Rx_ptr_in] = Buf[i];

        // Update the circular buffer index
        APP_Rx_ptr_in++;

        // Loop the index if necessary
        if (APP_Rx_ptr_in == APP_RX_DATA_SIZE)
        {
            APP_Rx_ptr_in = 0;
        }
    }
    return USB_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Finally, there are a few other issues in your code. I expect you are aware of some of these, but I'll list them just in case:

1. The statement `uint8_t Buf[6] = "A";` only initializes the first value to 'A'. The remaining five values are '\0'. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18688971/3380131) for more information.
2. When the counter variable `i` exceeds your delay limit, it should be cleared back to zero.  **This could be a primary problem**.  Currently, when the delay finishes up the first time, it never delays again.  The outer `while` loop starts calling `VCP_DataTx(Buf, 6);` continuously. This will overflow the USB buffer and lead to all sorts of problems.
3. Once you fix the delay problem you will still get two calls to `VCP_DataTx(Buf, 6);` back-to-back with no delays. Once before the delay loop, and immediately again before the first delay. This shouldn't cause a problem but I wanted to point it out.

---

FYI, if you are only trying to send data back and forth to a PC via USB then you don't need to enable any USART functionality in the microcontroller.  The VCP example uses the USART as a data source (and destination), but you aren't trying to do that. Your data source is your `Buf[]` array.

Comment: I just used the function as an official example but ignored what it actually did. Also thanks for your three issues, I may have made more mistakes due to them.

Comment: Great, @AlexanderZhang, glad to help :)